# Correct way to write sequence of compound words with same ending

Tags: punctuation, list

I have multiple compound words with the same ending word:

- Listeneinträge,
- Gruppeneinträge,
- Inventareinträge,
- Verlaufseinträge

When I put them all in a sequence, is this the correct way to write?

> Listen- Gruppen- Inventar und Verlaufseinträge

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The hyphen can indeed be used to prereference a second element of a word which is only explicitly written once at the end of said list. However, the list requires commas between all entries that are not followed by *und*, and a hyphen at the end of *every* word where a bit is missing. So the correct way would be:

> Listen-, Gruppen-, Inventar- und Verlaufseinträge.

You can also use this at the beginning of an entry reversely:

> Eintragsprobleme, -möglichkeiten, -varianten und -chancen.

And you can combine the two:

> Gruppenein- und -austragungen.